# change baudrate in minimalmodbus

Tags: python, modbus, minimalmodbus

absolute beginner in Python (and Linux for that matter) trying to setup a modbus RTU master to control a stepper motor.

Eventually I will try to implement the solution on a Raspberry Pi, but for now I'm trying to get it to work on a Windows machine. I have python 3.8 installed and am using Pycharm as the IDE.

I think that for my purpose the library 'minimalmodbus' will have everything I need. However, I haven't figured out how to properly open the port yet. I'm trying to follow the documentation here: https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html

My particular slave device happens to be at 115200 baud, whereas the default port in minimalmodbus is at 19200.

In the examples this is given:

```
instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB1', 1, minimalmodbus.MODE_ASCII)
instrument.serial.port                     # this is the serial port name
instrument.serial.baudrate = 19200         # Baud
```

Further in the documentation it states the following, which I don't think I've understood:

> The module level constants minimalmodbus.BAUDRATE etc were removed in version 1.0

Anyway, this is what I have tried:

```
instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM5', 1, minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU)
instrument.serial.BAUDRATE = 115200
```

First line is accepted fine, the 2nd one is not. Same scenario for .baudrate . I must be missing something obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *the second line is not accepted*? Are you getting any errors? Have you tried `instrument.serial.baudrate=115200`? Capital letters are different than lower case for Python

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear: yes I've tried (copy/paste) : instrument.serial.baudrate=115200  , but the baudrate gets underlined in green and it says: "Typo:In word 'baudrate'"

Comment: I see. And have you installed and included serial with an import serial?

Comment: Are you sure this is not just the editor not recognizing the word `baudrate`?

Comment: I didn't consider it could have been the IDE, and effectively: the code actually compiles and executes as expected, even though the IDE suggests a typo. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that .baudrate was actually correct and compiled/executed as expected. Pycharm just indicated for some reason that "baudrate" could have been a typo